# How to use both Jupyter Notebook and Sublime for Data Science projects?

Tags: python, ide, sublimetext3, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm learning some Data Science and for that I'm using Python with Jupyter Notebook. Which I think it's great for data analysis, mainly because it’s super easy to run step-by-step code. You can see everything that is happening.

On the other hand, to do more complex projects, like a web crawler or an Object Oriented program to extract information from an API, I’m using Sublime Text3. IMO it’s simple, clean, light… perfect. Also I think that .py is better than .ipynb for that (I don't even know if it's possible to do OO with Jupyter).

My problem now is integrating these two tools. The best I can do now is convert the dictionnaires in some .csv file and read it manually in Jupyter notebook. Obviously it doesn't sounds very smart and it is like a temporary solution just for experimentation.

This is the first time I'm dealing with a project which I need to integrate more than one environment and not only working with the same languages with all the files in the same folder etc. so I'm not very familiar on how to approach that.

If someone could explain the right way of integrating these two IDEs, how to make all the process more 'automatic', if it's better to use some database and then extract with SQL or something like that I'd appreciate very much.

PS: Also, if you guys have any material on how should a Python Data Science project be organized it would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use [ipython magic commands](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html) to help me switch between a text editor and a ipython notebook.

Specifically, I like to experiment with the code in the Notebook for the reasons you mentioned, and then when I'm ready to integrate it as a class in a bigger system I use the `%%writefile filename.py` command which will export that cell into a .py file.

You can also use `%load filename.py` and `%run myfile.py` to bring .py files into the notebook.